# Can NuGet Packages which require .net 4 or higher be used with .net core 2.2?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am new to BackEnd Development.

Started writing API's for my project in .net core 2.2, now I need to integrate a package which it says requires .net 4 ?

What are my options here ?

Comment: What's the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the package is compiled against `netstandard2.0`, you may be able to use it in your .Net Core 2.2. project. If the package is not compiled against `netstandard2.0`, then the project author will have to compile it as a `netstandard2.0` library for you to use it in .NET Core 2.2.

More information on `netstandard` and what all that means here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Thanks for the doc link, made things clear, anyidea how I can find the netstandard of a package ? I could not find any answer on google

Comment: @user5667392 What's the package's name? Its nuget page will tell you what it's compiled against.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Razorpay, I didn't see the netstandard there

Comment: You’re right @user5667392 it isn’t there. Looks like someone added that support. You’d have to fork the project, merge in this branch, and create your own nuget package from the result: https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-dot-net/pull/32/files

Comment: Wow, did not see that one, thanks for bringing it up